# Google page events monitoring and analysis

Tags: google-analytics

I have read the Google page event documentation, but I am not sure I understand it correctly. I am new to Google analytics, and I have two questions:

1. Once I have google analytics enabled for my site (i.e. I have inserted the tracking code in my pages etc), do I need to set anything else up (at the Google end - i.e. in my Google analytics account)
2. It is not clear to me how the event data particularly, relating to how the data can be aggregated and analyzed.

For instance, if I want to track an event under category **category** for click action **action**, I will use the following code snippet:

`<a href="some-uri.htm" onclick="_gaq.push(['_trackEvent', 'category', 'action', 'label']);">Do Something</a>`

For the sake of simplicity, lets say I am interested in monitoring click events in my header and footer, and I want to find which pages the header and or footer is clicked most often.

How would I set things up so that I can analyze the header/footer clicks aggregated at the page level?

Answer (score 1):

1. It all depends on what you want to archive with the data. If you have implemented the tracking code correctly, all the basic functions will work out of the box. But I highly recommend that you start reading on web analytics, so you can get the full experience. One of the most important things, that I would recommend, would be to setup goals. This gives you a much more measurable metric.
2. I'm assuming that the footer and the header contains internal links, and you want to track which of these regions are used. Google Analytics just recently added this function, check out http://analytics.blogspot.dk/2012/11/announcing-enhanced-link-attribution.html

Answer (score 1):

Here's what you need to do to find out which page has the maximum no. of header and footer clicks.

In your header links, have this event -
Do Something

In your footer links, have this event -
Do Something

Once you do set this up, then you will see the events in GA under the Content section. You need to check the Event Pages report with the Secondary dimension as the Label. Do note that GA Event tracking can only track 500 events per session, so do not go overboard with this.